# Ehcache Manager

Tags: spring, ehcache

I have an application that use JDBCTemplate and Hibernate.

Both of this configure to use ehcache but exception thrown:

```
org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
```

JDBCTemplate configured using spring xml
Hibernate configured using hibernate.cfg.xml

Please help.

I tried to disable the default cache in ehcache.xml but failed and i have the shared property set to true which also caused fail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <!--<defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="50000"
        overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="0" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
        />
    -->

    <cache name="genericDao" eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="50000"
        overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />

    <cache name="reportDao" eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="50000"
        timeToIdleSeconds="28800" timeToLiveSeconds="28800"
        overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />


 </ehcache>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/ehcache/ehcache.xml"></property>
        <property name="shared" value="true"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"></property>
    </bean>
```

How to provide unique name in this case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two ehcache.xml configuration with different names.